# How to determine height of a row in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, uitextview

The font size of text in a UITextView is dynamic, how can I determine the current height of a row (i.e. `sizeWithFont`.height + line spacing height)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

```
textView.font.lineHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

Content size of the UITextView gives the height of the text in textView.

Comment: I need the height of one row (line) of text, not the full height. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the frame property you can access properties like height or width.

```
myTextView.frame.size.heigth;
```

If you get silly values, use bounds instead of frame.

Comment: I need the height of one row (line) of text, not the full height. Thanks.